# How to append a input value using jQuery

Tags: jquery, input

I'm trying to change the input value of my text box using jQuery here is my input

```
<input id="qty_10" class="input-text qty" name="qty" maxlength="3" value="1" style="display: none;" type="text">
```

and the jquery code

```
jQuery("#qty_10").val(selectedValue);
```

Here I need to change the input like this

```
<input id="qty_10" class="input-text qty" name="qty" maxlength="3" value="10" style="display: none;" type="text">
```

but the value is not changing can anyone help me.

```
function qtyaddcart(qtydrp,id){
  var selectedValue = qtydrp.value;
  var id=id;
  //alert(id);
  alert(" Value: " + selectedValue);
  jQuery("#qty_"+id).val(selectedValue);    
}
```

Here my problem is I have renamed the id in my input field actually I can't rename it so here I cant use the id or name to append the value to input field is there any other attribute to append the value `jQuery("add some other attribute here"+id).val(selectedValue);`

Comment: show us how selectedValue is defined :)

Comment: you need to share complete code

Comment: Are you asking how to set the value to `10` instead of `1`? If so, just set `selectedValue` to `10`

Comment: You need to let us know if `selectedValue` is a dynamic value. From where does `selectedValue` come and how is it set?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/hj3vo714/1/

```js
var selectedValue = 10;
$('#qty_10').attr('value', selectedValue);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="qty_10" class="input-text qty" name="qty" maxlength="3" value="1" type="text" />
```

**Solution explanation**
I have manipulated the **value** **attribute**.

Comment: I think `selectedValue` is a "dynamic" value

Comment: Hey thaks for your answer the actual problem is i have renamed the id this id i'm using to add the product in cart where this input box is a product quantity box now i need to append the value to the input box with out using the id and name is there any other attribute to set it

Comment: You can use class to target the input element. Here you go with an example https://jsfiddle.net/hj3vo714/2/

Comment: Welcome @ami :)

Comment: @ Shiladitya more than this is there any other option you can add any extra attribute in input field with that attribute can we change the value

Comment: Yes... You can add N number of attribute with custom name... Here you go with an example https://jsfiddle.net/hj3vo714/3/